# "Disjoint toolsets" vs. "disjointed toolsets"

Tags: adjectives, past-participles

I have only ever heard the expression *there are **disjoint** sets*, never that *there are **disjointed** sets*.

I believe it should be *disjoint sets*, but I don't have a good reason why. Does anyone have a more general rule that applies here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Disjointed" is indeed the main adjective form of "disjoint," but mathematics is a special case. When outside the academic field, "disjointed" is used to describe something that is separated at the joints or dislocated. In mathematics, "disjoint" is used to describe sets with no elements in common. Essentially, the answer is it's simply a matter of convention.

See the definition for [disjoint](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disjoint) and [disjointed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disjointed).

Answer (score 3):

The concept of [*disjoint sets*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets) comes from the world of mathematics and has nothing to do with *disjoint(ed) toolsets*. If you take a look at the definitions of the two words, you'll see that *disjoint* as an adjective is now obsolete outside of this mathematical sense:

> [DISJOINT](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disjoint)
>
> 1. *obsolete* : disjointed 1a
> 2. : having no elements in common <*disjoint* mathematical sets>
>
> [DISJOINTED](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disjointed)
>
> 1. a : being thrown out of orderly function <a *disjointed* society>
>    b : lacking coherence or orderly sequence <an incomplete and *disjointed* history>
> 2. : separated at or as if at the joint

So unless you're specifically talking about sets in a mathematical sense, I'd recommend:

> There are *disjointed* toolsets all over the place…